# open source pdf editor based on mupdf

Tags: pdf, editor, mupdf

This is not a program code question.

I would like to know if you know an open source pdf editor based on mupdf.

In fact, I just need the following features:

1. Highlight a  select rectangle. (And the feature delete a highlighted rectangle)
2. Add a line in some text (to indicate these text should be deleted or ignored). (And the feature to 
   delete this line)
3. Rotate a page or an entire pdf file.
4. Add a comment (annotation).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it can be done using mupdf, besides 3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a useful pdf editor based on mupdf

(1)[Editing a PDF with MuPDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFedit) And (2)[MuPDF wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MuPDF)

though there are other pdf editors which are free softwares.

1. [PDFedit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFedit)
2. [Pdftk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftk)

Hope that this will be of some help :)